# "Check Our other Apps" Button to redirect to publishers other apps

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to create a button which redirects users to developers apps list i.e `play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Developer` just like Rate us button.

I have use this code for the rate us button which unfortunately doesn't seems to work for the developers apps button.

```
val rateBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.rateBtn)
        rateBtn.setOnClickListener{
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            i.data = Uri.parse("market://details?id=$packageName")
            startActivity(i)
        }
```

I tried this code, but it would crash the app.

```
val appBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.appsBtn)
        appBtn.setOnClickListener{
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            i.data = Uri.parse("market://developer?id=developerid")
            startActivity(i)
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This `market://search?q=pub:<publisher_name>`
.Your Code should look like this:

```
val appBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.appsBtn)
        appBtn.setOnClickListener{
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            i.data = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:<publisher_name>")
            startActivity(i)
        }
```

Comment: This would fail if there is no Google Play on the device or is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This approach opens the Developer Page on Google Playstore which lists all the apps:

```
Intent target = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.vending");
if (target != null) {
    target.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    target.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=<dev_id>"));
    startActivity(target);
}
```